# Perl if not in an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hashtable

I am trying to write code that will update, insert, and delete rows in a database based on what is in another database. This will eventually happen automatically based on other criteria. The goal is for the tables to be identical. Database replication is not an option.

This question isn't really about MYSQL or the DBI module though, it is about comparing two arrays.

I have used `fetchall_arrayref({})` to make two arrays of hashes.

This is an example of the array for the original database table it is `$profile` in my code:

```
[
  { DESCRIPTION => "Default", ID => 0, NAME => "Default",  VERSION => "1.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 1, NAME => "Custom 1", VERSION => "1.2" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 2, NAME => "Custom 2", VERSION => "2.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 3, NAME => "Custom 3", VERSION => "6.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 5, NAME => "Custom 5", VERSION => "1.0" },
]
```

This is an example of the array for the database table I want to be like the other, it is `$profile2` in my code:

```
[
  { DESCRIPTION => "Default", ID => 0, NAME => "Default",  VERSION => "1.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 1, NAME => "Custom 1", VERSION => "1.1" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 2, NAME => "Custom 2", VERSION => "1.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 3, NAME => "Custom 3", VERSION => "6.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 4, NAME => "Custom 4", VERSION => "1.0" },
]
```

The following has worked for updating the entries where the ID is in both tables:

```
foreach my $l (@$profile) {
    my $id = $l->{ID};
    my $desc = $l->{DESCRIPTION};
    my $name = $l->{NAME};
    my $ver = $l->{VERSION};
    foreach my $i (@$profile2) {
        my $id2 = $i->{ID};
        my $desc2 = $i->{DESCRIPTION};
        my $name2 = $i->{NAME};
        my $ver2 = $i->{VERSION};
        if ($id eq $id2) {
                my $update = 'UPDATE PROFILE SET DESCRIPTION='."\'$desc\'".', NAME='."\'$name\'".', VERSION='."\'$ver\'".' WHERE ID='."\'$id\'".';';
                my $sth3 = $dbh2->prepare($update);
                $sth3->execute;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need code to find if an ID in `$profile` is not in `$profile2` insert that row into the database table for `$profile2` (`my $insert = 'INSERT INTO PROFILE(ID,VERSION,NAME,DESCRIPTION) VALUES('."\'$id\'".','."\'$ver\'".','."\'$name\'".','."\'$desc\'".');';`). And I need code that will check if an ID is in `$profile2` and not in `$profile` and then delete the row from the `$profile2` database (`my $update = 'DELETE FROM PROFILE WHERE ID='."\'$id2\'".';';`).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ack! Don't use `"'".$var."'"`! Use placeholders or `$dbh->quote($var)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;

my $profile1 = [
  { DESCRIPTION => "Default", ID => 0, NAME => "Default",  VERSION => "1.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 1, NAME => "Custom 1", VERSION => "1.2" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 2, NAME => "Custom 2", VERSION => "2.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 3, NAME => "Custom 3", VERSION => "6.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 5, NAME => "Custom 5", VERSION => "1.0" },
];

my $profile2 = [
  { DESCRIPTION => "Default", ID => 0, NAME => "Default",  VERSION => "1.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 1, NAME => "Custom 1", VERSION => "1.1" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 2, NAME => "Custom 2", VERSION => "1.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 3, NAME => "Custom 3", VERSION => "6.0" },
  { DESCRIPTION => "",        ID => 4, NAME => "Custom 4", VERSION => "1.0" },
];

sub findUpdates{
  my ($updated, $toBeUpdated) = @_;
  my @IDs2update;
  my %index = map {$_->{ID} => $_} @$toBeUpdated;
  foreach(@$updated){
    push @IDs2update, $_ unless defined $index{$_->{ID}};
  }
  return \@IDs2update;
}

my $addIntoProfile2 = findUpdates($profile1, $profile2);
my $deleteFromProfile1 = findUpdates($profile2, $profile1);

print "Add into profile 2:\n";
print Dumper($addIntoProfile2);
print "\n";
print "Delete from profile 1:\n";
print Dumper($deleteFromProfile1);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Add into profile 2:
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'ID' => 5,
            'NAME' => 'Custom 5',
            'DESCRIPTION' => '',
            'VERSION' => '1.0'
          }
        ];

Delete from profile 1:
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'ID' => 4,
            'NAME' => 'Custom 4',
            'DESCRIPTION' => '',
            'VERSION' => '1.0'
          }
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my @ids_in_p1 = map $_->{ID}, @$profile1;
my @ids_in_p2 = map $_->{ID}, @$profile2;

my $ids_in_p1 = map { $_ => 1 } @ids_in_p1;
my $ids_in_p2 = map { $_ => 1 } @ids_in_p2;

for my $id (grep !$ids_in_p2{$_}, @ids_in_p1) {
   print("In p1 but not in p2: $id\n");
}

for my $id (grep !$ids_in_p1{$_}, @ids_in_p2) {
   print("In p2 but not in p1: $id\n");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could simply track all of the IDs you see from `$profile`, then when you encounter the same ID in `$profile2` you remove that ID from the array. When your loops finish executing the array of IDs will have all of the IDs that were in `$profile`, but not `$profile2`:

```
my @ids; 
foreach my $l (@$profile) {
    my $id = $l->{ID};
    my $desc = $l->{DESCRIPTION};
    my $name = $l->{NAME};
    my $ver = $l->{VERSION};

    # save ids from $profile
    push @ids, $id;

    foreach my $i (@$profile2) {
        my $id2 = $i->{ID};
        my $desc2 = $i->{DESCRIPTION};
        my $name2 = $i->{NAME};
        my $ver2 = $i->{VERSION};

        if ($id eq $id2) {
           # remove elements that were in $profile2
           @ids = grep { $_ != $id2 } @ids;
           my $update = 'UPDATE PROFILE SET DESCRIPTION='."\'$desc\'".', NAME='."\'$name\'".', VERSION='."\'$ver\'".' WHERE ID='."\'$id\'".';';
           my $sth3 = $dbh2->prepare($update);
           $sth3->execute;
        }
    }
}

# Now @ids is the array of all IDs in $profile, but not $profile2
foreach my $id ( @ids ) {
   # create insert
}
```